# Using Array(Tuple(LowCardinality(String), Int32)) in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    id Int32,
    values Array(Tuple(LowCardinality(String), Int32)),
    date Date
) ENGINE MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(date)
ORDER BY (id, date)
```

but when executing the request

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM table
WHERE (arrayExists(x -> ((x.1) = toLowCardinality('pattern')), values) = 1)
```

I get an error

```
Code: 49. DB::Exception: Received from clickhouse:9000. DB::Exception: Cannot capture column 3 because it has incompatible type: got String, but LowCardinality(String) is expected..
```

If I replace the column 'values' 
values Array(Tuple(String, Int32))
then the request is executed without errors.

What could be the problem when using Array(Tuple(LowCardinality(String), Int32))?

Comment: It looks like it is the bug: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7815

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until it will be fixed (see [bug 7815](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/7815)), can be used this workaround:

```sql
SELECT uniqExact((id, date)) AS count
FROM table
ARRAY JOIN values
WHERE values.1 = 'pattern'
```

---

For the case when there are more than one *Array*-columns can be used this way:

```sql
SELECT uniqExact((id, date)) AS count
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        date, 
        arrayJoin(values) AS v, 
        arrayJoin(values2) AS v2
    FROM table
    WHERE v.1 = 'pattern' AND v2.1 = 'pattern2'
)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that I can’t use ARRAY JOIN twice to restrict to two such fields

Answer (score 1):

> values Array(Tuple(LowCardinality(String), Int32)),

Do not use `Tuple`. It brings only cons.
It's still *2 files on the disk.
It gives twice slowdown then you extract only one tuple element

https://gist.github.com/den-crane/f20a2dce94a2926a1e7cfec7cdd12f6d

```
valuesS Array(LowCardinality(String)),
valuesI Array(Int32)
```

Comment: I use  Tuple to store Key-Value values, and filtering by key values, I use values. Storing in two independent arrays is not suitable for me.

Comment: @ask125342 all high order functions accept multiple arrays

select arrayFilter((v, k) -> k = 'a', values, keys) from
(select ['a','a','b','a'] keys, [1,2,3,4] values)